# Simple Past or Past Perfect

Tags: past-tense

I would like to answer these questions and i need your help

The question is :

*Put the verbs in the brackets into either the past simple or the past perfect

1.It ................ (stop)raining for a while,but now its raining again.

2.The town is very different now.It ................ a lot. (change)

3.I did German at school but I ................ most of it.(Forget)

4.Look there is an ambulance over there.There ................ an accident.(be)

5.The police ................ three people but later they let them go.(arrest)

Comment: Welcome to ELL. The site does not work this way. What you think? What's the confusion? What research is done for this?

Comment: Though to help - *had stopped*, *has changed*, *have forgotten*, **has been*, *had arrested*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.1.It ......**stopped**.......... (stop)raining for a while,but now its raining again.

2.The town is very different now.It .**has changed**............... a lot. (change)

3.I did German at school but I ...**have forgotten**............. most of it.(Forget)

4.Look there is an ambulance over there.There ..**has been..............** an accident.(be)

5.The police .....**had arrested...........** three people but later they let them go.(arrest)
past-tense
As you can see, the Present Perfect is used for actions which happened in the past and are related to the present. On the other hand, the P. ast simple is used for actions which happened in the past and are not related to the present. As for the Past perfect tense,it is used for an action which happened before another past action or before a stated time in the past.